# Empty Value When Using Cascading Dropdowns in .NET Core 6

Tags: c#, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I working Cascading Dropdowns using ajax in .Net Core 6. I want to select all color according to the product. So when I invoice the product, i want to select the product and then the next dropdown list will only show the color of that product available. Here is the view [drop down list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TKrk.png)

So I use ViewBag to transfer the list of products to the view.Here the code

```
//In controller

ViewBag.Product = new SelectList(_context.Products, "ProductId", "ProductName");
//In view
 <td>
     <select name="" id="productList" class="ddlProductItemsId">
         @foreach (var item in lstProduct)
         {
             <option value="@item.ProductId">@item.ProductName</option>
         }
     </select>
</td>

//dropdown list color
<td>
    <select id="colorId"></select>
</td>
```

And then I use Ajax to do the cascading dropdowns :

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     getColorByProduct();
 });

 $("#productList").change(function () {
     getColorByProduct();
 });

 function GetColorByProduct() {
     $.ajax({
         url: '@Url.Action("GetColorByProduct", "Invoice")',
         type: 'GET',
         data: {
             id: $("#productList").val()
         },
         success: function (data) {
             $('#colorId').empty();
             $(data).each(function (index, item) {
                 $('#colorId').append('<option value="' + item.colorId + '">' + item.colorId + '</option>');
             });
         }
     });
 }
//Here the GetColorByProduct method

public JsonResult GetProductByColor (int id)
{   
       
    return Json(_context.ProductItems.Where(n=>n.ProductId == id)
        .ToList());    
}
```

Product have many productItems and productItem have color attibute so we need to query to find the color of that productID [my database desgin if you guys confused](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4nKq.png) My problems is when I change the product, the color doesn't change. I have tried enter to url GetColorByProduct?=1 and json return like this

```
[
    {
        "productItemsId": 30,
        "productId": 1,
        "colorId": 1,
        "productCode": "AFWhite",
        "image1": "",
        "image2": null,
        "image3": null,
        "image4": null,
        "color": null,
        "product": null,
        "productVariations": []
    },
    {
        "productItemsId": 41,
        "productId": 1,
        "colorId": 2,
        "productCode": "sd",
        "image1": null,
        "image2": null,
        "image3": null,
        "image4": null,
        "color": null,
        "product": null,
        "productVariations": []
    }
]
```

And the view [color] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5nvY.png) So that means method work correctly but when i change the product in the dropdown, the color not change.
Does anyone know the problem? I really appreciate any instructions. Thank you

Comment: could possibly be a simple typo?: " $("#productList").change(function () {
     getColorByProduct();
 });"  should be " $("#productList").change(function () {
     GetColorByProduct();
 });"?

Comment: also this bit may be incorrect: url: '@Url.Action("GetColorByProduct", "Invoice")',  Seems like that should be something like: url: 'GetColorByProduct?id=' + $("#productList").val() ?

Comment: btw, easier to just use the .get() function... so something like let url = "GetColorByProduct?id=" + $("#productList").val();  $.get(url, function (data) {....}

Comment: can you write example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the JS script, I noticed that the function name is `getColorByProduct`, but when you are calling it, you are using `GetColorByProduct` . Please keep the corresponding names and capitalization of the function the same.

In the Ajax method, the request url is `@Url.Action("GetColorByProduct", "Invoice")`, but from your controller code, we find that the action name is `GetProductByColor`, instead of  `GetColorByProduct`, so please change them to use the same name.

Here is an example of changing the color option based on the selected of the product, and we can also set the background color:

```
<select id="colorId" >
     <option value="a">aa</option>
</select>

$(document).ready(function () {
            GetColorByProduct();
});

$("#productList").change(function () {
            GetColorByProduct();
});

function GetColorByProduct() {
     $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("GetProductByColor", "Invoice")',
         type: 'GET',
         data: {
             id: $("#productList").val()
         },
         success: function (data) {
             $('#colorId').empty();
             $(data).each(function (index, item) {
                        $('#colorId').append('<option value="' + item.colorId + '"  style="background-color:' + item.color + '" ;" >' + item.colorId + '</option>');
             });
         }
     });
}
```

Controller:

```
public JsonResult GetProductByColor(int id)
{
// do some serch
    return Json(productItems);
}
```

when I select value:

[image]

[image]